# Google API Client connect results in INTERNAL_ERROR

Tags: android, google-drive-api

Trying to connect to the Drive API, I've implemented code that matches what's in the Drive Quickstart project, but something's still not right. When calling connect(), my onConnectionFailed method is called with status SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, and I then call result.startResolutionForResult. This presents a small dialog prompting me to select an account. After selecting my account, onActivityResult shows a status of RESULT_OK, but my onConnected method is not called and instead I'm right back in onConnectionFailed with a status this time of INTERNAL_ERROR, and I am not connected. Any ideas on where to look next?

I'm pretty sure that I set up my OAuth credentials with my SHA1 fingerprint from debug.keystore, package name, etc. I noticed that when I set up the credentials in the console, it informed me that my Client ID was something like "myapp-1234". Am I supposed to do anything with this?

Comment: Scratch this. The answer was simply "patience". From browsing some more questions here I got a hint that registering my credentials would not give me instantaneous access, but rather it would take some time for the data to be spread out over various servers. I went back to the app a couple hours later and it started working immediately!

Answer (score 1):

You can't set up OAuth credentials and immediately run your app for authorization. It apparently takes some time for the registration to make it to the appropriate servers. I went back a couple hours later and everything started working.